# Getting the hDC for a System.Windows.Media.FontFamily

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I'm filtering fonts using the Panose.FontFamily Type, which I get using:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern int GetOutlineTextMetricsA(IntPtr hdc, int cbData, IntPtr lpOtm);
```

However, I'm starting with a System.Windows.Media.FontFamily. Coming from the list: System.Windows.Media.Fonts.SystemFontFamilies

I haven't found a way to get the hDC for a Media.FontFamily. Therefore, I need to match it to System.Drawing.FontFamily. Coming from the list: System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families

The only way I've found to map a Media.FontFamily to a Drawing.FontFamily is by comparing Media.FontFamily.Source to Drawing.FontFamily.Name. Which is not perfect since their respective names often don't exactly match. I figure I'm getting a match for at least 90% of the fonts.

Using a Drawing.FontFamily does have a way to get the hDC of a font.

A decent solution will be a better way (other than by name) to map a Media.FontFamily to Drawing.FontFamily. An ideal solution would to get an hDC directly from a Media.FontFamily.
Another ideal solution would be to get the OUTLINETEXTMETRICS struct without needing to import the base method.
A perfect solution would be getting the panose family type from a Media.FontFamily with involving a Drawing.FontFamily or importing a method.

First, I get the list of Media.FontFamily like this:

```
foreach (Media.FontFamily font in Media.Fonts.SystemFontFamilies.OrderBy(_ => _.Source))
```

Then I get the list of Drawing.FontFamily like this:

```
System.Collections.IEnumerator fontIter = Draw.FontFamily.Families.OrderBy(_ => _.Name).GetEnumerator();
```

Then I compare the Media.FontFamily.Source to the Drawing.FontFamily.Name. I've found that Drawing.FontFamily.Name contains Media.FontFamily.Source quite often.
After getting the Drawing.FontFamily, it's an easy step to convert it to a Drawing.Font:

```
Draw.Font drawFont = new Draw.Font(drawFamily, 9.0F);
```

And from that I get the Panose Family Type:

```
enum PanoseFontFamilyTypes
    {
        PAN_ANY = 0, PAN_NO_FIT = 1, PAN_FAMILY_TEXT_DISPLAY = 2, PAN_FAMILY_SCRIPT = 3,
        PAN_FAMILY_DECORATIVE = 4, PAN_FAMILY_PICTORIAL = 5
    }

public PanoseFontFamilyTypes PanoseFontFamilyType(Draw.Font font)
        {
            byte bFamilyType = 0;
            IntPtr hdc = (IntPtr)0;
            IntPtr hFontOld;

            try
            {
                hdc = GraphTool.GetHdc();
                hFontOld = SelectObject(hdc, font.ToHfont());
                int bufSize = GetOutlineTextMetricsA(hdc, 0, (IntPtr)0);
                IntPtr lpOtm = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(bufSize);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.WriteInt32(lpOtm, bufSize);
                int success = GetOutlineTextMetricsA(hdc, bufSize, lpOtm);
                if (success != 0)
                {
                    int offset = 61;
                    bFamilyType = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(lpOtm, offset);
                }

                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(lpOtm);

                SelectObject(hdc, hFontOld);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Message: {ex.Message}\r\nStackTrace:\r\n{ex.StackTrace}", "Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                GraphTool.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
            }

            return (PanoseFontFamilyTypes)bFamilyType;
        }
```

Looking for a less convoluted solution.

Comment: For anyone that's curious. The Panose FamilyType works the most often, of the various font attributes, to determine if a font is Wingding, dingbat, or some other set of images.

Just keep in mind that fonts are created by people who may mistakenly incorrectly set descriptive values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find a way to map a Media.FontFamily to a Drawing.FontFamily that did not involve a string comparison. However, I did find a more reliable way to do the mapping. The problem is that Media.FontFamily.Source (the font name) often does not exactly correspond to a Drawing.FontFamily.Name.

```
  Media.FontFamily font=<your font>;
  Typeface face = new Typeface(font, FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, FontStretches.Normal);
  if (face.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out GlyphTypeface typeFace))
  {
    Drawing.FontFamily drawFont = Drawing.FontFamily.Families.FirstOrDefault(_o => typeFace.Win32FamilyNames.Any(_i => _i.Value.Equals(_o.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
    return new Tuple<FontUtility.OutlineTextMetric, bool>(GetOutlineTextMetric(drawFont, fontData), typeFace.Symbol);
  }
```

The GetOutlineTextMetric method Gets the OUTLINETEXTMETRIC using the code found here: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/GetOutlineTextMetrics.html

The name in Win32FamilyNames does map exactly to a Drawing.FontFamily.Name. I was able to get rid of the contains string algorithm I was using.

This also has the added benefit of getting the Symbol boolean, which at least for every font I have installed is 100% accurate to identify a symbol font. (e.g. wingdings)